# Java Client returns 401 Unauthorize Error But working in Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

From PostMan i am calling API. with bearer token in header.
I am getting 200 response.

But when I am calling same API form Java, I am getting 401 Unauthorized error.
Below is the code I implemented:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
 headers.setBearerAuth("token");
 ResponseEntity<String> response  = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri,String.class,headers);
```

Please guide.

The cURL requet is:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://myURL' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer myToken'
```

Comment: How did you expect us to verify if that is anywhere near what you are doing in Postman?

Comment: Can you please provide your postman request (cUrl) in question ?

Answer (score 0):

May be your token get invalid.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail?